# what does launchctl config user path do?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, zsh, launchctl

I was having a strange problem with PATH environment variable in MacOS that I spent several hours to debug:

- Some time ago, when I was trying to fix the issue IntelliJ terminal PATH variable not the same with iTerm, I followed an online article and executed this:

  `sudo launchctl config user path $PATH`
- Apparently this command sets and persists the value of PATH variable at that moment of time somewhere and that variable is loaded even before my shell is loaded whenever I start a new zsh session. Only recently I recognized this issue because I removed some paths location setting in my `zshrc` and  the `PATH` variable still didn't reflect
- My question is where does that command store the `PATH` variable value? and how does it load that value before my shell is loaded?

(For people who wonder how I fixed the issue: I executed the command again to set path to empty value: `sudo launchctl config user path ''`)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `sudo launchctl config user path <...>` command updates `/private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/config/user.plist`:

```
$ cat /private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/config/user.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PathEnvironmentVariable</key>
    <string>/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Tested on my system, which is currently macOS 14.2.1 (AppleSilicon). You can replace `user` with `system` to operate on the system-wide preferences. Both require sudo, oddly enough.

You can query `launchd`'s current **custom** PATH setting (will return an empty string if you haven't configured one) with:

```bash
launchctl getenv PATH
```

You can query the *default* `PATH` by executing:

```bash
sysctl -n user.cs_path
```

To undo any customizations, you can issue:

```bash
sudo defaults delete /private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/config/user.plist PathEnvironmentVariable
```

(requires a reboot to take effect)

Comment: out of curiosity, how did you find out about this? there are not many documentation online about launchctl

Comment: @PhuongNguyen: I brute forced it: I added a nonexistent dummy path using the command, e.g. `xyzzy` and then used ripgrep to search the entire filesystem for that string. Took a while but it found it.

Comment: Do you know if there a way to make it persist across reboots?

Comment: @szx: It does persist across reboots, but unfortunately it doesn't apply to apps which are automatically restarted after reboots. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/198282.